¿Cuál ensamblador es más rápido entre FASM, NASM, MASM y GAS en la generación de código?
Estaba investigando sobre ensambladores y de casualidad me encontré con una publicación que decía que FASM es más rápido que NASM, MASM y GAS.
Pienso que es algo ilógico teniendo en cuenta de que todos son ensamblador.
Sé que la sintaxis de cada uno es diferente, pero al final son ensambladores.
Al final me surgió la duda de saber cual es más rápido si es que hay uno, pero soy muy nuevo en ASM y no encontré mucha información al respecto, excepto por artículos muy técnicos que no entendí.

¿ Cabría la posibilidad de que lo que leíste se refiriera a la velocidad de generación de código, y no a la velocidad de ejecución del mismo ?

¿Podrías añadir la fuente donde has visto que FASM sea más rápido?

Pues sí era la velocidad de generación de código. @Trauma

Estuve buscando, pero ya no volví a ver la publicación. Como dije, la encontré por casualidad y no soy de los que guardan páginas. Una disculpa por eso. @ordago

Hasta donde sé, FASM y YASM son los más rápidos para generar código. Es decir pasar del código fuente ensamblador al código objeto en el formato que sea.
NASM parece ser el más lento, sobre todo cuando el código es grande. Sobre MASM no sé, pero imagino que en Windows aportará ciertas ventajas.
Sin embargo, todos estos ensambladores son para plataformas Intel. Si tienes que utilizar otras plataformas GAS es tu única opción (o alguno de los sistemas propietarios de pago que existen para plataformas específicas). Además GAS ofrece la mejor integración con C.
El código generado, como bien dices es la traducción directa del ensamblador a código máquina. Aún así varios de estos ensambladores ofrecen opciones de optimización, normalmente relativas a utilizar instrucciones para palabras más cortas (BYTE, WORD, DWORD en lugar de QWORD para 64bits).
Por ejemplo de la página del manual de GAS cuando genera código para intel podemos leer:
-O0 | -O | -O1 | -O2 | -Os
     Optimize instruction encoding with smaller instruction size.  -O
     and -O1 encode 64-bit register load instructions with 64-bit
     immediate as 32-bit register load instructions with 31-bit or
     32-bits immediates, encode 64-bit register clearing instructions
     with 32-bit register clearing instructions, encode 256-bit/512-bit
     VEX/EVEX vector register clearing instructions with 128-bit VEX
     vector register clearing instructions, encode 128-bit/256-bit EVEX
     vector register load/store instructions with VEX vector register
     load/store instructions, and encode 128-bit/256-bit EVEX packed
     integer logical instructions with 128-bit/256-bit VEX packed
     integer logical.

     -O2 includes -O1 optimization plus encodes 256-bit/512-bit EVEX
     vector register clearing instructions with 128-bit EVEX vector
     register clearing instructions.  In 64-bit mode VEX encoded
     instructions with commutative source operands will also have their
     source operands swapped if this allows using the 2-byte VEX prefix
     form instead of the 3-byte one.  Certain forms of AND as well as OR
     with the same (register) operand specified twice will also be
     changed to TEST.

     -Os includes -O2 optimization plus encodes 16-bit, 32-bit and
     64-bit register tests with immediate as 8-bit register test with
     immediate.  -O0 turns off this optimization.

Todo eso (bueno, una buena parte, no todo) viene a decir que si escribes código como este:
  mov rax, 100

El ensamblador generará
move eax, 100

Que es más corto y rápido ya que no hay que leer los 64 bits del valor inmediato de memoria
Para YASM también se pueden hacer optimizaciones.
NASM ofrece también unas cuantas opciones de optimización.
Así que diría que a primera vista tienes más opciones de generar un código más rápido (o más corto) con GAS o NASM que con los otros ensambladores, pero el tipo de optimizaciones que ofrecen son sencillas y fáciles de implementar directamente en tu propio código.
A modo de sumario:

Velocidad de Generación del binario:  Utiliza FASM o YASM
Facilidad de Uso: Utiliza NASM
Versatilidad: Utiliza GAS (Multi plataforma e integración C con gcc y clang)

Supongo que MASM caería en la categoría generar código para Intel y Windows.

Gracias, eso respondió mi duda.

n resumen, si buscas rapidez en la generación de código binario, FASM y YASM son las mejores opciones. Para optimizaciones más avanzadas y versatilidad en diferentes plataformas, GAS podría ser la mejor elección, mientras que NASM ofrece facilidad de uso. MASM es ideal para generar código para plataformas Intel y Windows. Cada ensamblador tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, por lo que la elección dependerá de tus necesidades específicas.

Gracias por el resumen
